# Store matrix-like data in dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, matrix

I  have one loop nested inside another one:

```
position={}
n=2
for i in range(n):
i=str(i)
    for j in range(n):
        j=str(j)
        position[str(i+j)]= #whatever (in my case an object)
```

This way the key values of the dictionary are the indices from the matrix and I just need to call with `position['11']` to get it.
Is there a better way to join `i` and `j`? And store (and create) a matrix-like data?

PS: I know about the `numpy` library but I haven't succeed to install it yet... but that is another question...

Comment: To make things simpler, give us your inputs, and your expected outputs.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac It has no input, apart from the n, it is part of a map generator object that I am trying to make, the object is one I defined previously, which has a random definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use `numpy`, you could use nested lists (equivalent to multidimensional arrays in C):

```
position=[]
n=2
for i in range(n):
    position.append([])
    for j in range(n):
        position[i].append(some_object)
```

And then you reference it using `position[i][j]`.

An alternative method would be to use a flat list and index into it using calculated values (basically what happens when you index into a 2D array in C and the like, as those are stored as one contiguous array and the compiler performs some math on the multiple indices you supply to index into that underlying flat array):

```
position=[]
n, m = 2, 3
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m):
        position.append(some_object)

# do something with the object at (i, j)
position[m*i + j].do_something() # there are m elements between (i, j) and (i+1, j)
```

Comment: I like your first solution, but I thought that the dictionaries where better to store this kind of data, even thought the reference is a little bit more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

Your dictionary is a headache waiting to happen. It can't distinguish between row 1, column 11 and row 11, column 1.

If you can't get NumPy working, the standard solution to your problem is a nested list:

```
matrix = [[whatever() for i in xrange(n)] for j in xrange(n)]
```

You would index this with `matrix[i][j]`.

You could also use a dict indexed with tuples:

```
matrix = {(i, j): whatever() for i in xrange(n) for j in xrange(n)}
```

and index it with `matrix[i, j]`. This may surprise people who need to maintain your code.

Comment: I've used the dict-with-tuple-keys solution in the past when I needed to store sparse-matrix-style data, but it's probably not as good of an idea for dense matrices.

Comment: Darn, I just finished writing almost the same thing, only 2 minutes slower.  +1.

Comment: I didn't thought it would matter, but with python 3.3 I don't have the `xrange` function, so your solutions don't work. But thanks for pointing the problems of my system. I have no maintainer this is just for learning python

Comment: @Llopis: That's because `xrange` is just `range` in Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

The "right" answer is to figure out how to install Numpy, since that will improve your programming toolset much more than writing a homegrown pseudo-matrix class.

However, if you want to do it your way, this is going to cause problems:

```
position[str(i+j)]
```

How will you tell the difference between  `2,11` and  `21,1`.?

So your dict key will need to be something like

```
position["{},{}".format(i,j)]
```

Or as @user2.3M suggests:

```
position[(i,j)]
```

But you don't really want to be building complex strings or new tuples for each "matrix" access.
Unless the map is very large and sparse, you are much better off using one of the list-based versions in @JAB's answer.

Comment: The OP stringified `i` and `j` before adding, so distinguishing `1, 2` and `2, 1` will work. `2, 11` and `21, 1` won't, though.